# automatically run html which includes "Tableau Javascript API code" over Phantomjs

Tags: node.js, command-line, phantomjs, tableau-api, javascript-api-for-office

Is it possible to run [tableau-javascript-api](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/js_api/en-us/JavaScriptAPI/js_api.htm) code, which works with html, over [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/)?

I'm working on a project to get Tableau data over tableau-javascript-API and then test them if it shows corrects data.

Among this project, I have to run all these jobs automatically on Jenkins. For them, I need some tool like maven/command line executer something like this.

At the moment I try to use Phantomjs. But even I included the `tableau-2.min.js`, Phantomjs doesn't recognize/know "new tablea.Viz(parameters)".

Does anyone have experience with my situation? Are there any other tools you suggest to me?

Here I add my javascript code:

```
var viz;

function initViz() {

    var container = document.getElementById("container");

    var url = "http://my_tableau_link";

    var options = {

        hideTabs: true,
        hideToolbar: true,
        onFirstInteractive: function () {
            getSummaryData(Timo_Live_Auswertung);
        }
    };
    viz = new tableau.Viz(container, url, options);
}

function getSummaryData(object){
    var worksheet = viz.getWorkbook().getActiveSheet().getWorksheets().get(object.SHEET);
    console.log(worksheet.getName());

    options = {
        maxRows: 0, 
        ignoreAliases: false,
        ignoreSelection: true,
        includeAllColumns: false
    };

    worksheet.getSummaryDataAsync(options, object).then(function(table) {
        var columns = table.getColumns();
        var data = table.getData();
        var niceData = reduceToObjects(columns, data);
        console.log(niceData);

        for (var i = 0; i < niceData.length; i++){
            if (niceData[i]["OFFER"] == "4044"){
                console.log(i + ": " + niceData[i]["OFFER"] == "4044");
                console.log(i + ": " + niceData[i]["Planstunden Kategorie"]);

            }
        }

    });
}

function reduceToObjects(cols,data) {

    var fieldNameMap = $.map(cols, function(col){
        var fieldName = col.getFieldName(); 
        return fieldName;
    });

    var dataToReturn = $.map(data, function(d) {
        return d.reduce(function(memo, value, idx) {
            memo[fieldNameMap[idx]] = value.formattedValue; 
            return memo;
        }, 
    {});
    });

    return dataToReturn;
}

var Timo_Live_Auswertung = {
    SHEET : "Timo Live Auswertung (%)", 
    Kennzahlnamen : "Kennzahlnamen",
    Kennzahlwerte : "Kennzahlwerte",
    Kunde: "Kunde",
    Label_list: "Label list",
    Laufzeit: "Laufzeit",
    OFFER: "OFFER",
    Planstunden_Kategorie: "Planstunden Kategorie",
};

initViz();
```

Here is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
        </div>

        <script src="http://my_tableau_server/javascripts/api/tableau-2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you spell Tableau correctly?  `new tablea.Viz(parameters)` has a spelling error as you posted above.

Comment: oh, you are right. There above i missed the letter. In my code I didn't miss it.

Comment: Can you add your full code?  Can't tell what is going on just from one snippet.  Also, you should look at the [get data](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/js_api/en-us/JavaScriptAPI/js_api_samples_get_data.htm) samples which show exactly how to do this.  I'm not familiar with phantomjs, per se, but if you should try to get your code running in a regular browser and if that works then try to move to the next step of getting it running in phantomjs.

Comment: I edited there above my codes. I searched a lot about this problem. Do you may know other solution? Solution doesn't have to be phantomjs.

Comment: What errors are you getting?  And I'm still not sure what your ultimate goal is.  If you just want to get the data you could just use [tabcmd](https://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/tabcmd-get-export-csv-crosstab).  If you really need a headless browser you could also check [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/).

Comment: I'm very new for programming. So I defined my issue not really clear. I'll try to explain again what my goes is. I have to write kind of regression test if the tableau shows the correct numbers. For this I needed to get datas from tableau. So I used tableau javascript api. https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/js_api/en-us/JavaScriptAPI/js_api.htm. It worked well. Now i want to automate this job. There are some trouble because I'm not an admin of the tableau I work on. Cos tabcmd doesn't work, I may try #Selenium.

Comment: See this [trick](http://www.vizwiz.com/2014/03/the-greatest-tableau-tip-ever-exporting.html) to get the data just by adding .csv to the end of the URL.  Your scenario sounds pretty backwards to how most companies do it, honestly.  You should be validating the data either before it gets into Tableau or in Tableau itself.  Just because you are pulling the underlying data doesn't guarantee that you are presenting the data appropriately in the Viz, but I digress as that seems out of scope for your actual question.